Ad Campaign Insights not breaking down correctly based on `link_url_asset` in Facebook Insights API
I am facing the same problem as mentioned in this question, Why some ads is not breaking down by link_url_asset, the only difference is that I am pulling data on "Campaign" level.
Since the question was asked long back and there's no answer, so posting it again with my wrapper question.
When I am not applying breakdown, I am getting X number of impressions. But when I apply breakdown on link_url_asset, the breakdown happens but when I add the impressions, the sum does not match with X (less than X).
The reason I want to do breakdown is because I want to pull the utm_campaign value from the website_url attribute in link_url_asset.
I am hitting following endpoint with the params -
/GET https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/act_{ACCOUNT_ID}/insights?level=campaign&fields=account_name,account_id,campaign_name,impressions,spend,actions&time_range={"since":"2024-04-07","until":"2024-04-07"}&access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}&filtering=[{field: "action_type",operator:"IN", value: ['link_click']}]&breakdowns=link_url_asset&use_account_attribution_setting=true

I am not able to figure out from the Facebook documentation that what am I missing here.
